Find the Smallest Data Type for a Number
Recently I had to implement this problem in c#, and thought it would make for a good code golf.
Your goal is to output the smallest unsigned data-type a 64 bit unsigned number can fit into.
Input: An unsigned 64-bit number (or the closest builtin equivalent in your chosen language)
Output: A number representing the bytes of the smallest unsigned data-type the input value can fit into (1, 2, 4, or 8)
Data Type Max Values:
byte => 255
ushort => 65535
uint => 4294967295
ulong => 18446744073709551615

Examples:
0 => 1 (byte)
255 => 1 (byte)
256 => 2 (ushort)
500 => 2 (ushort)
60000 => 2 (ushort)
4294967295 => 4 (uint)
4294967296 => 8 (ulong)
18446744073709551615 => 8 (ulong)

This can be done using lzcnt, if statements, regex, bit manipulation, etc. (creative solutions & languages encouraged!)
This is a code-golf, so shortest solution wins!

How strict is the output format? Can we output 4 other distinct values?

@Arnauld Only output 1, 2, 4, or 8. The original problem required 1,2,4 or 8 only, so I'll stick to that. (Nice solution btw!)

Wait, this is not a duplicate of an age-old existing challenge?

Vyxal, 7 bytes
₈τL∆l⌈E

Try it Online!
  L     # Length
 τ      # when converting to base
₈       # 256
        # (i.e. number of bytes required) 
      E # 2 to the power of
   ∆l   # log2 of that
     ⌈  # rounded up


x86_64 machine code, 14 bytes
B0 FF                mov         al,0FFh  
48 0F BD C0          bsr         rax,rax  
0F BD C8             bsr         ecx,eax  
B0 40                mov         al,40h  
D2 C0                rol         al,cl  
C3                   ret  


If x < 223, its type is 1, or 20
If 223 ≤ x < 224, its type is 2, or 21
If 224 ≤ x < 225, its type is 4, or 22
If 225 ≤ x < 226, its type is 8, or 23

To apply this, we can calculate y = log2(log2(x)), and then z = 2 ** y, with suitable offsets and rounding.
To ensure good behavior near 0, the code first ensures x ≥ 255 (I think greater than 3 should be enough; used 255 for safety).

Python, 33 bytes
f=lambda n:n<256or 8-6*f(n**.5)%8

Attempt This Online!
Returns True for 1.
How?
Same idea as @xnor's comment here. The tricky bit was fixing the fp issue cheaply.

JavaScript (ES11), 29 bytes
Expects a BigInt.
f=(n,k=8n)=>n>>k?2*f(n,k+k):1

Try it online!

So you're checking for the exit condition floor(n / 2**x) == 0 , where x is the amount of bits you're checking for in each pass (8, 16, 32, 64), then returning 2**depth. Cool solution!

Haskell, 32 29 27 bytes
f n=until(\b->n<256^b)(*2)1

Try it online!
EDIT: -3 bytes because I realized I could drop the -1 if I switched to using <
EDIT 2: -2 bytes thanks to @xnor's suggestion to use 256^b.

Looks like you can write n<256^b

Retina, 63 bytes
$
¶$`¶256¶65536¶4294967296
N`¶.+
Lm`^(.+)¶(.+¶)*\1$
C`¶
T`34`48

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Unfortunately I had to use Retina 1 for this as Retina 0.8.2 uses 32-bit arithmetic for sorting. Explanation:
$
¶$`¶256¶65536¶4294967296

Append a copy of the input and 256, its square and squared square.
N`¶.+

Sort the copy among the powers.
Lm`^(.+)¶(.+¶)*\1$

Find where it ended up.
C`¶

Count how many squares were needed, plus one.
T`34`48

Translate into a number of bytes.

05AB1E, 7 bytes
₁вg.²îo

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
₁в       # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a base-256 list
  g      # Pop and push its length
   .²    # Take the logarithm_2 of that
     î   # Ceil it
      o  # Take 2 to the power that
         # (which is output implicitly as result)


Perl 5 -p, 47 bytes
$_=$_>9e10?8:$_?1<<1+log(log()/log 256)/log 2:1

Try it online!
The 10 bytes of $_>9e10?8: could have been dropped if log had more floating point accuracy I think. And $_=$_>=1<<32?8:$_>65535?4:$_>255?2:1 is 36 bytes Try it online!
Inspired by the Python from @Lucenaposition: $_=[1,2,4,4]->[log($_|1)/log 256]||8 Try it online! 36 bytes.

Charcoal, 15 bytes
ＩＸ²Ｌ↨÷⊖Ｌ⍘Ｎ²¦⁸¦²

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
         Ｎ      Input as an integer
        ⍘       Converted to string base
          ²     Literal integer `2`
       Ｌ        Length
      ⊖         Decremented
     ÷          Integer divided by
            ⁸   Literal integer `8`
    ↨           Converted to base
              ² Literal integer `2`
   Ｌ            Take the length
  ²             Literal integer `2`
 Ｘ              Raised to that power
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print

The first base conversion converts 0 to "0" while the second one converts it to []. This makes a difference when taking the length.

Python 2, 37 bytes
lambda n:'12448888'[len(bin(n))-3>>3]

Try it online!
Outputs a string (if it is allowed).
Python 2, 45 bytes
lambda n:0x88884421>>((len(bin(n))-3)/8*4)&15

Try it online!
Outputs a number.

Python 3.8 (pre-release),  59   47   38  34 bytes
-12 bytes by having 5 more minutes to codegolf.
-9 bytes by stealing Arnauld's idea.
-4 bytes from Arnauld.
f=lambda n,k=8:n>>k<1or 2*f(n,2*k)

Try it online!

37 bytes

or 34 bytes if you don't mind returning True instead of 1 (it quacks like a 1!)

f=lambda n:n<256or 2*f(n**.5) almost works for 29 bytes (with True==1), but float precision messes up the last test case

37 bytes: F=lambda n,b=1:n>>b*8and F(n,b+b)or b

APL+WIN, 26 bytes
Prompts for integer
¯1↑((2⍟1⌈⎕)≥0,2*3+⍳3)/2*⍳4

Try it online Thanks to Dyalog Classic!

MathGolf, 13 bytes
8421Γgæ♠▬k>~Þ

Try it online.
Explanation:
8421          # Push 8,4,2,1 separated to the stack
    Γ         # Wrap all four into a list: [8,4,2,1]
     g        # Filter this list by,
      æ       # using four character as inner code-block:
       ♠      #  Push 256
        ▬     #  Take 256 to the power the current value
         k    #  Push the input
          >   #  Check whether the 256 to the value is larger than the input
           ~  # After the filter: dump all remaining digits to the stack
            Þ # Only keep the last one
              # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)


R, 29 27 bytes
\(n,k=2^(3:6))k[n<2^k][1]/8

Attempt This Online!
The last test-case is too large for R.

Uiua, 11 bytes
⍜ₙ⌈2⌈ₙ256+1

Try it: Uiua pad
⌈ₙ256+1 -- The number of bits needed to represent the number is the logarithm with base 256 of 1 + the input, rounded up.
⍜ₙ⌈2 -- "under logarithm ceiling 2", so \$2^{\lceil log_2 n \rceil}\$ (where \$ \lceil x \rceil \$ means x rounded up), yielding the smallest power of 2 greater than n.

Google Sheets, 44 bytes
=ifs(A1<2^8,1,A1<2^16,2,A1<2^32,4,A1<2^64,8)


Google Sheets uses IEEE 754 double-precision with a significand of 53 bits for pretty much everything, so cannot go all the way up to 64-bit unsigned.
The output format rules specified in the question are quite rigid. This alternative version outputs an array where the first true value marks the minimum bytes required by the unsigned integer (23 bytes):
=sort(A2<2^2^{3,4,5,6})



The original problem I was solving could only work with the outputs 1,2,4 or 8. And, looser output format rules was never suggested in the sandbox post. However, I am more than happy to loosen the output rules (so that any 4 distinct values could be outputted) if this inspires more creative and "golfy" answers. Do you recommend I edit the post to make this change?

Flexible I/O formats are encouraged. See Always allow flexibility, within reason,
Keep your golfing in your code, not in inputs and outputs, and
Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods.
But it's also good to not alter rules after answers have already been posted. In comments, Arnauld specifically asked if it's OK to output other values, and you responded "no", so perhaps it's better to stick by the original rules.

Sounds good. I'll keep in mind the good practice of having flexible I/O for my future questions, but I'll stick with a "no" for this question :)

Japt, 10 bytes
Inspired by Kevin's MathGolf solution.
@<G²pX}a!²

Try it
@<G²pX}a!²     :Implicit input of integer U
@              :Function taking an integer X as argument
 <             :  U is less than
  G            :    16
   ²           :    Squared
    pX         :    Raised to the power of X
      }        :End function
       a       :Apply the following method to the non-negative integers,
               : returning the first result that returns true
               : when passed through that function
        !²     :Power of 2

